# org-babel for vimscript or most similar language

Tags: org-babel, syntax-highlighting

Since I couldn't find anything as per title, does anyone know what org-babel language could be used as workaround?

Currently I surround code blocks with `#+begin_src sh`, though in particular the comments `"` are obvisouly not displayed correctly.

Or in other words (offtopic): What language uses `"` for comments and is supported by org-babel?

Comment: [Vim script specification](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html)

Comment: @Tobias I don't quite understand. Could you please elaborate on the usage of your provided link with org-babel?

Comment: That is a comment to spare the others the search for the Vim script specification. Maybe you should add that link to your question. Afterwards I can delete my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [vimrc-mode](https://github.com/mcandre/vimrc-mode/) provided on melpa.

Install it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `vimrc-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Orgmode provides font lock of source blocks for all major modes. So font-locking of source blocks works for `vimrc-mode`:

[image]

You do not have `org-babel-execute:vimrc`. So execution of vimrc blocks is not possible.